# vs code intellisense broken with c++17 explicit template deduction

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17, intellisense

I have an issue with vs code intellisense for c++17. The following code runs perfectly fine, but vs code tells me it is wrong. It doesn't understand the explicit template deduction. The installed extensions can be seen on the left hand side of the image. I'm using vs Code in combination with wsl2. The same thing happenes when using vs code on an ubuntu server.

[image: Wrong intellisense]

Am i maybe missing an extension for c++17?

Comment: You probably didn't set it to assume C++17.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: If you didn't set it to assume C++17, when compiling include  `-std=c++17`.

Comment: How have you configured vs code? Please show a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I didn't know that i had to set the cppstandard in vs code to c++17 manually.

Simply go to: File -> Preferences -> Settings,
search for: cppstandard,
set Cpp Standart to c++17